# System.Net.Http.HttpClient not timing out after set time

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin.forms, httpclient

I'm using HttpClient to handle web requests. I'll perform the request like so...

```
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(Uri, stringContent);
```

The timeout is set in the http client setup and I then call it in the class with IHttpClientFactory dependency.

```
// Setup HttpClient
        services.AddHttpClient("ApiName", client =>
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("BaseUri");
            client.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 8);
        });
```

I've inspected httpClient before it runs to see if its using the correct API and it is, the timeout is set to 8 seconds. However, the request takes around a good 1-2 minutes to timeout. I'm not sure why this is happening.

I've tried using a CancellationToken like so...

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        cts.CancelAfter(8000);
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(Uri, stringContent, cts.Token);
```

and waiting for the exception to occur but it still takes 1-2 minutes.

Comment: After further testing this seems to be an issue when using HttpClient in Xamarin.Forms. Creating a new .NET Core console app with the http client times it out after the desired amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [HttpClient.Timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout) documentation, a DNS query may take up to 15 seconds to return or time out. However that does not explain the 1-2 minute delay you are seeing.

Have you looked at ["Better timeout handling with HttpClient"](https://thomaslevesque.com/2018/02/25/better-timeout-handling-with-httpclient/)? I don't know if it will work, but rather than using `PostAsync` you might try building the POST with `HttpRequestMessage` and use `SendAsync` instead, similar to the example in the article:

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://foo/");
request.Content = stringContent;
request.SetTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(8)); // Uses HttpRequestExtensions from article
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(8));
var response = await client.SendAsync(request, cts.Token);
```

Comment: I'll have a go using that and mark this as correct if it worked, thanks.